# Number of digits in Seaborn heatmap axies

Tags: python, seaborn

[image]

Hi, here there is a colormap that I have generated with Seaborn. I want to reduce the number of digits in both the axis and to put the yaxis in scientific notation. How can I do it? Thank you!

Some additional information. I have used the heatmap method from Seaborn. In input I had a file structured in this way

phi       p        myvalue
0         3        10
0         4        15
1         3        9
1         4        21

The data are fake, but the structure is true. The file has been inserted in a dataset named colormap Then, as suggested in the Seaborn guide, I have built the pivot table with the command

```
colormap = colormap.pivot(index = 'phi', columns = 'p', values = 'myvalue')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it:

To remove the scientific on x axis:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='x')
```

To limit the number of digit on y ( where g=sns.heatmap(...)):

```
ylabels = ['{:,.2f}'.format(x) for x in g.get_yticks()]
g.set_xticklabels(ylabels)
```

Comment: The first command return me an error : AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter. The second one convert the scale in 0 to 360. Why?